# Argument has type Any even though it is strongly typed in generic base class (TypeScript bug?)

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I these classes:

```js
abstract class BaseExampleService<TModel extends Model, TOmitAttrs extends string = ""> extends BaseApiModelService<
    TModel,
    TOmitAttrs
> {
    abstract add(data: Omit<Payload<TModel>, TOmitAttrs>): OptimisticModelResult<TModel>
}

class ExampleService extends BaseExampleService<Example, "test"> {
    add(example): AddModelResult<Example> {
        // TODO: Why does `example` have type `Any` instead of `Omit<Example, "test">`?
    }
}
```

Even though the `example` argument in `ExampleService.add` should clearly be `Omit<Example, "test">`, it is interpreted as `Any`.

Even if implementing an interface instead of using inheritance:

```
interface BaseService<TPayload> {
    add(data: TPayload): void
}

class UserService implements BaseService<User> {
    add(data) {
        // TODO: `data` implicitly has type `any`
    }
}
```

This is, of course, completely different from how most typed languages work. You don't normally lose your types just because they're generic.

How come?

Comment: That's just how inheritance works in typescript: https://tsplay.dev/NaREpm

Comment: That's not how any other typed language I know works. Surely, there must be a way to have the correct type inferred.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this was proposed and closed:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1373

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/6118

I guess generic base classes are just kind of neutered in TypeScript, and will remain so. :(